# Linear fit on semi-log scale using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I have been playing around with getting the linear fit straight (and I only succeeded by accident). Please help me understand why this code plots a straight line and what is happening when I change plt.xscale

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data
x = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100]
y = [0.0, 29.80899, 41.297, 50.22667, 55.605, 60.20733, 65.050, 66.018, 68.4767]

# creates figure
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', linestyle = '')  # plots data
plt.xlim(-0.01, 150)  # sets the x limits of the current axes

x[0] = 10**(-4)  # replaced zero at index [0] with approximation

# generate linear fit
p = np.polyfit(np.log10(x), y, 1)  # generates m,b values
polynomial = np.poly1d(p)  # creates equation for linear fit of degree 1 with m,b values
log10_y_fit = polynomial(np.log10(x))  # generates values for y axis to be plotted

plt.plot(x, log10_y_fit, 'b-')  # plots linear fit in blue
plt.xscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-3, subs=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])  # converts x-axis to symmetric log scale

plt.show()
```

[straight graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKlAE.png)

however, when I change

```
plt.xscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-3, subs=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])  # converts x-axis to symmetric log scale
```

to something else, like

```
plt.xscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-1, subs=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])  # converts x-axis to symmetric log scale
```

I get a "bent" line like so

["bent" graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNxeW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symmetric logarithmic scale is usually used for symmetric signals (i.e. varying between positive and negative values). In your case the signal is positive, so I recommend using the logarithmic scale with `log` (see below).

**The reason for signal to bend:** the symlog scale bending effect comes from the `linethres` value, which indicates at which `x` value the log scale goes from negative to positive values (see the [matplotlib symmetric log scale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.SymmetricalLogScale) for more information). If the `linethres` value is higher than your lowest x-axis point, the signal "bends" to go from positive to negative log scale with showing anyway all the values (squeezed on a short scale).

- Here is the output of your code with a low threshold value. The bend is here but invisible

  ```py
  plt.xscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-4)
  ```

  [image: symlog with low threshold value]
- Now with a higher threshold value, the signal must reach 0 faster than from its definition in order to allow symmetric log scale.

  ```py
  plt.xscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-1)
  ```

  [image: symlog with high threshold value]
- Finally, in your case, you should better use the `log` scale:

  ```py
  plt.xscale('log')
  plt.xlim([1e-1, 1e2])  # this if you want to play with axes limits
  ```

  [image: log scale]